# Moving resources to expansion file

Tags: android, resources, drawable, apk-expansion-files

I have a project with several hundreds of image resources located in the res folder.

Since its size is ~150MB, I figure that in order to upload it to the play store I will have to create expansion files.

Now, I suddenly find this line in the Android documentation, under expansion files: "Develop your application such that it uses the resources from your expansion files in the device's shared storage location."

However, I use the getDrawable(ID) all through the application.

Is there a way for me to not go line-by-line and reference the new expansion file?